# How to convert ISO Date to 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' in mongodb from embedded array of documents?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

There's a 'Created' field in my collection, the date format is ISO date. How can I convert it to 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'?

Document sample:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("432babb4d3281999g902a378"),
    "ID" : "290283667",
    "Data" : {
        "Product-2713890" : {
            "Created" : ISODate("2016-08-23T20:55:39.437Z"),
            "Product" : "Product-2713890"
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("432babb4d3281999g902a378"),
    "ID" : "290283667",
    "Product" : "Product-2713890",
    "Created" : "2016-08-23 20:55:39"

}
```

Here is my code:

```
db.getCollection('BasicInfo').aggregate([
{$match:{Type:'subscriptions'}},
{$project: {hashmaps: { $objectToArray: '$$ROOT.Data'},ID:'$$ROOT'}},
{$project: {ID:'$ID.ID',
            Product: '$hashmaps.v.Product',
            Created: '$hashmaps.v.Created'} },
{$unwind:'$Product'},
{$unwind:'$Created'}
])
```

I tried to use `$dateToString` like below, but it gave the error message : "can't convert from BSON type array to Date"

```
db.getCollection('BasicInfo').aggregate([
{$match:{Type:'subscriptions'}},
{$project: {hashmaps: { $objectToArray: '$$ROOT.Data'},ID:'$$ROOT'}},
{$project: {ID:'$ID.ID',
            Product: '$hashmaps.v.Product',
            Created: {$dateToString:{format:'%Y-%m-%d',date:'$hashmaps.v.Created'}}} },
{$unwind:'$Product'},
{$unwind:'$Created'}
])
```

Comment: It would greatly increase the visibility and context of the question to get help if you can update the question with documents stored in mongodb and what is the desired output looks like. [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following aggregation query should get the expected output.

With the help of [**`$addFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) **why?** because `Data` value in sample document converted with `$objectToArray` will be at 0th index. [Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8kl78OHv8mf)

**Note:** considering that `Data` field can contain more than one product information in which case before we pick the first element the hashmaps array should be filtered `$filter` (one way) based on product key to work this out correctly.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{Type:'subscriptions'}},
  {
    $addFields: {
      hashmaps: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT.Data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "ID": 1,
      "hashmaps": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$hashmaps",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "ID": 1,
      "Product": "$hashmaps.k",
      "Created": {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
          date: "$hashmaps.v.Created"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**++ Updated Query based on comments:** Case where the data would indeed have multiple products. Using [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      productsMap: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT.Data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "Products": {
        $map: {
          input: "$productsMap",
          as: "p",
          in: {
            Product: "$$p.k",
            Created: {
              $dateToString: {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                date: "$$p.v.Created"
              }
            },
            ID: "$ID",
            _id: "$_id"
          }
        }
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Sample output:** [playground with new query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XY_v2psqQ5V)

```
[
  {
    "Products": [
      {
        "Created": "2016-08-23 20:55:39",
        "ID": "290283667",
        "Product": "Product-2713890",
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
      },
      {
        "Created": "2017-07-23 20:55:39",
        "ID": "290283667",
        "Product": "Product-6943532",
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution solved my issue. But like you mentioned in the answer, there are some documents that contain multiple products, e.g. [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6R6Rmckvl0-)  how to print out all the products instead of only the first one?

Comment: @tysss Have updated the answer with new query and playground link. See if that achieves the required result for multiple products scenario.